# Using perl to cycle through a list of values (x) and compare to another file with value ranges

Tags: perl, while-loop

I have two files. One file has a list of values like so

**NC_SNPStest.txt**

```
250 
275 
375
```

The other file has space delimited information. Column one is the first value of a range, Column two has the second value of a range, Column 5 has the name of the range, and Column eight has what acts on that range.

**promoterstest.txt**

```
20 100 yaaX F yaaX 5147 5.34 Sigma70 99
200 300 yaaA R yaaAp1 6482 6.54 Sigma70 35
350 400 yaaA R yaaAp2 6498 2.86 Sigma70 51
```

I am trying to write a script that takes the first line from file 1 and then parses file 2 line by line to see if that value falls in the range is between the first two columns.

When the first match is found, I want to print the value from file 1 and then the values in file 2 for columns 5 and 8 from the line with the match. If no match is found in File 2 then just print the value from File 1 and move on.

It seems like it should be a simple enough task but I'm having an issue cycling though both files.

This is what I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $PromoterFile, '<', 'promoterstest.txt' or die $!;
open my $SNPSFile, '<', 'NC_SNPtest.txt' or die $!; 
open (FILE, ">PromoterMatchtest.txt");

while (my $SNPS = <$SNPSFile>) {
   chomp ($SNPS);

   while (my $Cord = <$PromoterFile>) {
      chomp ($Cord);

      my @CordFile =split(/\s/, $Cord); 
      my $Lend = $CordFile[0];
      my $Rend = $CordFile[1];
      my $Promoter = $CordFile[4];
      my $SigmaFactor = $CordFile[7];

      foreach $a ($SNPS) 
      {
         if ($a >= $Lend && $a <= $Rend)
         {
            print FILE "$a\t$CordFile[4]\t$CordFile[7]\n";
         }
         else 
         { 
            print FILE "$a\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
close FILE;
close $PromoterFile;
close $SNPSFile;
exit;
```

So far my output looks like so:

```
250
250     yaaAp1  Sigma70
250
```

Where the first line of file 1 is being called and file 2 is being cycled through. But the `else` command is being used on each line of file 2 and the script never cycles through the other lines of file 1.

Comment: Are both files sorted?

Comment: Also - are there any unique keys in there?

Comment: Could you indicate expected maximum number of lines in both input files?   It would help to know if you want simple or "big data efficient" (complicated) solution.

Comment: Both files are sorted in ascending order. This will be used on big data sets. With up to 10000 entries in file 1 and 6000 in file 2. Column 5 should be unique IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you're not resetting your progress through the second file. You read one line from `$SNPSFile`, check that against ever line in the second file.

But when you start over, you're already at the end of file, so:

```
while (my $Cord = <$PromoterFile>) {
```

Doesn't have anything to read.

A quick fix for this would be to add a `seek` command in there, but that'll make inefficient code. I'd suggest instead reading file 1 into a array, and referencing that instead.

Here's a first draft rewrite that may help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

open my $PromoterFile, '<', 'promoterstest.txt'     or die $!;
open my $SNPSFile,     '<', 'NC_SNPtest.txt'        or die $!;
open my $output,       ">", "PromoterMatchtest.txt" or die $!;


my @data;

while (<$PromoterFile>) {
    chomp;
    my @CordFile    = split;
    my $Lend        = $CordFile[0];
    my $Rend        = $CordFile[1];
    my $Promoter    = $CordFile[4];
    my $SigmaFactor = $CordFile[7];

    push(
        @data,
        {   lend        => $CordFile[0],
            rend        => $CordFile[1],
            promoter    => $CordFile[4],
            sigmafactor => $CordFile[7]
        }
    );
}

print Dumper \@data;

foreach my $value (<$SNPSFile>) {
    chomp $value;
    my $found = 0;
    foreach my $element (@data) {
        if (    $value >= $element->{lend}
            and $value <= $element->{rend} )
        {
            #print "Found $value\n";
            print {$output} join( "\t",
                $value, $element->{promoter}, $element->{sigmafactor} ),
                "\n";
            $found++;
            last;
        }

    }
    if ( not $found ) {
        print {$output} $value,"\n";
    }
}

close $output;
close $PromoterFile;
close $SNPSFile;
```

First - we open file2, read in the stuff in it to an array of hashes. (If any of the elements there are unique, we could key off that instead.)

Then we read through SNPSfile one line at a time, looking for each key - printing it if it exists (at least once, on the first hit) and printing just the key if it doesn't.

This generates the output:

```
250     yaaAp1  Sigma70
275     yaaAp1  Sigma70
375     yaaAp2  Sigma70
```

Was that what you were aiming for?

Aside from that 'Dumper' statement which outputs the content of `@data` as thus:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'sigmafactor' => 'Sigma70',
            'promoter' => 'yaaX',
            'lend' => '20',
            'rend' => '100'
          },
          {
            'sigmafactor' => 'Sigma70',
            'promoter' => 'yaaAp1',
            'rend' => '300',
            'lend' => '200'
          },
          {
            'promoter' => 'yaaAp2',
            'sigmafactor' => 'Sigma70',
            'rend' => '400',
            'lend' => '350'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: Will I have to get data::dumper from cpan? I have really worked with any packages yet. But I feel now like I really need to go look into some.

Comment: No. `Data::Dumper` is part of perl core. But it really is the core tool for diagnosing problems with data structures.  But getting `cpan` fired up is no bad thing. `perl -MCPAN -e shell` will do almost all the set up automatically, and you get access to some amazingly good and useful modules.

Comment: When I use this on my real files my output looks good. Dumper is printing to STDOUT which is fine I can make maybe a .o.txt file that collects the output so I can see warnings better.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on a programming solution. It's important to

- Use lexical file handles and the three-paremeter form of `open`
- Keep to lower-case letters, digits and underscores for local variables

I have also used the `autodie` pragma to remove the need to test the status of `open` explicitly, and the `first` function from the core library [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) to make the code clearer and more concise

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use List::Util 'first';

my @promoters;
{
    open my $fh, '<', 'promoterstest.txt';
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my @fields = split;
        push @promoters, [ @fields[0,1,4,7] ];
    }
}

open my $fh,     '<', 'NC_SNPStest.txt';
open my $out_fh, '>', 'PromoterMatchtest.txt';
select $out_fh;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my ($num) = split;
    my $match = first { $num >= $_->[0] and $num <= $_->[1] } @promoters;
    if ( $match ) {
        print join("\t", $num, @{$match}[2,3]), "\n";
    }
    else {
        print $num, "\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
250 yaaAp1  Sigma70
275 yaaAp1  Sigma70
375 yaaAp2  Sigma70
```